# EmptyResultSetException not thrown when expected

Tags: android-room

A query is run to retrieve records from a table one-by-one, which are email recipients. After sending an email to a recipient, the status of the sending is updated for the recipient. The table where this status is stored has a relationship with the table used to store the actual messages to be sent. Because I'm using Room, the query for retrieving the message to send gets automatically run again. This will continue in a loop until all the recipients have been sent an email. This works with the Rx stream below. The problem I have is that after the last email is sent, the query is not throwing an EmptyResultSetException, which is what I expect it to do when no more records are found. Without that exception, I have no way of knowing when all the emails have been sent.

```
val msgToSendPublisher = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0)

msgToSendPublisher.flatMap { startPos -> App.context.repository.getMessageToSend() }
    .flatMap { messageToSend ->
        App.context.repository.sendMessage(messageToSend)
            .doOnError {
                messageToSend.failureSending = true
            }
    }
    .zipWith( // 1 second delay between emissions.
        Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
        BiFunction { item: MessageToSend, _: Long -> item })
    .flatMap { messageToSend ->
        App.context.repository.storeMessageSent(messageToSend)
            .doOnError {
                messageToSend.failureSending = true
            }
    }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        { messageToSend ->

        },
        { ex ->
            if (ex is EmptyResultSetException) {

            } else {

            }
        },
        {
           // Done
        }
    )
```

DAO

```
@Query(
    "SELECT blah blah blah"
)
fun getMessageToSend(): Observable<MessageToSend>
```

MessageToSend.kt

```
class MessageToSend(
    var content: String? = null,
    var chatId: String? = null,
    var firstName: String? = null,
    var lastName: String? = null,
    var totalMessagesToSend: Int? = null
): MessageRecipientBase()
```

What could be preventing EmptyResultSetException from not being thrown? Or is it being thrown but caught somewhere I am not aware of. I have a suspicion that Room only throws this exception when you explicitly run a query. But if a query is run because Room forces a query to run after data in a related table is updated, it is possible that Room may decide not to throw any exception.

NOTE: I've put a breakpoint on each of the doOnError handlers as well as the error handler in the subscriber but none of them get hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room will only throw an exception when the return type is `Single`.

Indeed the documentation lacks clear explanation, but I tested all the cases [here](https://medium.com/@musooff/rxjava-and-room-complete-guide-sheet-7fca5b49804e)

From the tests that I checked, here is a basic summary

- #### Single

  - `Single<User>` ==> will send User if exists or throws exception is not exists
  - `Single<List<User>>` ==> will always send list of users (empty list if not exists). Never throws an exception
- #### Maybe

  - `Maybe<User>` ==> will send User if exists or just completes the maybe if not. Does not throw any exeptions
  - `Maybe<List<User>>` ==> works like `Single<List<User>>`. Will always send list of users (empty list if not exists). Never throws an exception
- #### Observable (Flowable works analogously)

  - `Observable<User>, Observable<List<User>>` ==> will keep listening to the changes in database. If anything updates, it will send otherwise it nothing happens. No exception is thrown.

These results actually makes sense but it would have been better if they have documented well

Answer (score 0):

This is cleary a mistake in the Android documentation. The documentation states the following:

> Thrown by Room when the query needs to return a result (e.g. in a
>   Single query) but the returned result set from the database is
>   empty.

This is incorrect. It should be written that the exception is thrown ONLY when the return type is Single. In my code, I was returning an Observable and the generated code for Room clearly shows that it returns null if there are no records to return. But it will throw an exception if Single is used. It might also throw an exception for other types like Maybe but I didn't check to see if that is true. I had to modify my DAO to return a Single.

Comment: Maybe because the Single give a result when it complete, but not the Observable(which call onNext and maybe not supported by Room), but anyways, you could improve your implementation, eg. : use Observable.interval() if you want to add delay between emission